# How to include conf/routes file into distribution zip?

Tags: playframework, routes

With *play -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf dist* command I can create a distribution zip file which includes my application.conf file and start.sh. Surprisingly, conf/routes in not included into the distribution zip and therefore any request to my application leads to "Action not found".

Where should I place conf/routes to be found by the application? I tried $scriptdir/conf/routes, CLASSPATH, but same "Action not found".

Cheers,
Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conf.routes` is compiled and included into JAR as set of `*.class` files.

Comment: `play dist` itself does not build correct jar of my application. When I run `sbt clean compile package-bin` I get jar with `*.class`, but then `sbt dist` creates(overrides) new jar with no `*.class` files.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but if you can — file a bug.